# How can I structure a try-catch-finally block to handle errors inside finally?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dll, error-handling, unmanaged

I've got a problem with making calls to a third-party C++ dll which I've wrapped in a class using `DllImport` to access its functions.

The dll demands that before use a session is opened, which returns an integer handle used to refer to that session when performing operations. When finished, one must close the session using the same handle. So I did something like this:

```
public void DoWork(string input)
{
    int apiHandle = DllWrapper.StartSession();

    try
    {
        // do work using the apiHandle
    }
    catch(ApplicationException ex)
    {
        // log the error
    }
    finally
    {
        DllWrapper.CloseSession(apiHandle);
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that CloseSession() sometimes causes the Dll in question to throw an error when running threaded:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

I'm not sure there's much I can do about stopping this error, since it seems to be arising from using the Dll in a threaded manner - it is supposed to be thread safe. But since my CloseSession() function does nothing except call that Dll's close function, there's not much wiggle room for me to "fix" anything.

The end result, however, is that the session doesn't close properly. So when the process tries again, which it's supposed to do, it encounters an open session and just keeps throwing new errors. That session absolutely *has* to be closed.

I'm at a loss as to how to design an error handling statement that's more robust any will ensure the session always closes?

Comment: I guess the question is, how should the error be "handled"?  If closing the session throws an error from 3rd party code, and we can't proceed without closing the session, then what next?  I mean, you can put another `try/catch` inside of that `finally`, but how would you actually respond to the error?  If the 3rd party tool isn't working, what can be done?

Comment: If this is caused by threading, then perhaps you can work around the issue by using a [lock(){}](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) statement around StartSession() and CloseSession() method calls.

Comment: @David The third party tool fails are intermittent - when you try it a second time, it usually works. My actual code is currently an awful mess of recursions and control flow trying to ensure this always happens. I'm loathe to add more, but if I have to, I have to :(

Comment: @MattThrower Have you actually tested using this not-really-thread-safe 3rd party library through only one thread at a time?  If you do that, does the problem go away?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes, and yes.

Comment: Is this a 32-bit or 64-bit DLL?  Handles are usually pointer-sized things.  You should probably be using IntPtr instead of int as your handle type.

Comment: @MattThrower "Yes" to both? The failures disappear?  So for some reason, you *can't* use the library single-threaded?

Comment: @AndrewHenle No. It's being used in the processing of enormous files. I absolutely need the multi-threading or else it's going to literally take days to perform a single operation.

Comment: @MattThrower, does multi-threading break only `CloseSession` functionality or does it break other functionality as well?

Comment: @Serge It breaks other functions too. I'm just putting a lock statement (and IntPtr) into my code, to see if it helps. Since the error is intermittent it may be a while before I can tell. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Serge I'm not sure I'd trust the library to produce correct results when used by multiple threads given the way it's broken.  Since the files being processed are "enormous", I'd try processing each file with a separate process since the overhead of starting another process for each file should be negligible. That should fix the problem of multithreaded use of the DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the wrapper to include disposal of the external resource and to also wrap the handle. I.e. instead of representing a session by a handle, you would represent it by a wrapper object.

Additionally, wrapping the calls to the DLL in `lock`-statements (as @Serge suggests), could prevent the multithreading issues completely. Note that the lock object is static, so that all DllWrappers are using the same lock object.

```
public class DllWrapper : IDisposable
{
     private static object _lockObject = new object();

     private int _apiHandle;
     private bool _isOpen;

     public void StartSession()
     {
         lock (_lockObject) {
             _apiHandle = ...; // TODO: open the session
         }
         _isOpen = true;
     }

     public void CloseSession()
     {
         const int MaxTries = 10;

         for (int i = 0; _isOpen && i < MaxTries; i++) {
             try {
                 lock (_lockObject) {
                     // TODO: close the session
                 }
                 _isOpen = false;
             } catch {
             }
         }
     }

     public void Dispose()
     {
         CloseSession();
     }
}
```

Note that the methods are instance methods, now.

Now you can ensure the closing of the session with a using statement:

```
using (var session = new DllWrapper()) {
    try {
        session.StartSession();
        // TODO: work with the session
    } catch(ApplicationException ex) {
        // TODO: log the error
        // This is for exceptions not related to closing the session. If such exceptions
        // cannot occur, you can drop the try-catch completely.
    }       
} // Closes the session automatically by calling `Dispose()`.
```

You can improve naming by calling this class `Session` and the methods `Open` and `Close`. The user of this class does not need to know that it is a wrapper. This is just an implementation detail. Also, the naming of the methods is now symmetrical and there is no need to repeat the name `Session`.

By encapsulating all the session related stuff, including error handling, recovery from error situations and disposal of resources, you can considerably diminish the mess in your code. The `Session` class is now a high-level abstraction. The old `DllWrapper` was somewhere at mid distance between low-level and high-level.

Comment: Thanks for this. I like very much where you're going with it as a means to solve the problem and tidy the code at the same time. An initial prototype with this method seems to have slowed down the processing speed a lot and I'm not sure why. Am investigating - will be happy to accept if I can iron out the kinks.